# How to add a string with breakrule to a PHP array to use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, string, replace

I'm constructing an array in PHP to use it in my Javascript code. So I'm looping over all the posts (Wordpress) and push all the values to a string - which is the Javascript array:

```
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    $title = get_the_title();
    $address = get_field('address');
    $phone = get_field('phone');

    $shops = $shops . "['".$title."','".$phone."','".$address."'],";

    echo $shops; // for testing.
endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The input of the address is street, number BREAKRULE zip and city. Example:

```
Sint Pieterskaai 39
8000 Brugge
```

And that specific breakrule breaks the string to use as an array in Javascript.
Here is a screenshot of the HTML output:

[image]

As you can see, there is a `<br>` after the house number.

I have already tried to replace the `$address` variable with this, but without any luck:

```
$address = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "<br>"), '', $address);
```

Comment: `json_encode` is what you need instead of inventing the wheel.

Comment: Have you tried [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

Comment: Mmmmm [`nl2br()`](https://php.net/nl2br) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @u_mulder said in his comment, use `json_encode` to encode an **PHP** Array to *JSON string* instead of creating a strange string data, like you do here:

> $shops = $shops . "['".$title."','".$phone."','".$address."'],";

After that in your **JavaScript** code you can use `JSON.parse()` to retrieve data in form of an Array as well.
If you want to transfer data between **PHP** and **JavaScript** I would recommend using **AJAX** instead of inserting/echoing data directly to DOM.

That way your data will be more secure and can't be directly found on the markup.
See this post for more information about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/15182618

If you still prefer to do that this way then I have prepared a simple example for you:

**In PHP you have:**

```
<?php

$PHParray = ['Foo','Bar','Baz'];    //creating our Array in PHP - I assume you know how to do this in at least two ways :)

//adding values to our Array (you can use array_push or other method if you want)
$PHParray[] = 'Quo';
$PHParray[] = 'Vadis';

/*
... rest of the code ...
*/

//converting array to JSON string and adding it to the DOM of our site
echo '<div id="our-data" style="display: none;">'.json_encode($PHParray).'</div>';
?>
```

**And then your HTML with JavaScript:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <script>
        let dataDiv = document.getElementById("our-data"),  //getting element created earlier in PHP that contains our data as JSON string
            JSarray = JSON.parse(dataDiv.innerText);        //creating an Array from the JSON string
        dataDiv.remove(); //removing this element from the DOM after fetching data

        console.log(JSarray);
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Console output** (I'm using Google Chrome):

[image]

As you can see it's an Array with the data we expected.

So, it's that simple. You can copy the code above and change it so it suits your needs. Cheers!